# Could there be any difference between "all in one" and "in one"?

Tags: meaning

I found these two expressions here [Oxford Dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/one) and I don't know why one is used and not the other one.

> 1 - She's a mother and company director **in one**.
>
> 2 - It's a public relations office, a press office and a private
>   office **all in one**.

Perhaps "all in one" is only used with 3 or more elements or "all in one" is more emphasized, I don't know.

Comment: Drago, #1 could seem a bit ironic if "she" was said "mother and company director *all in one*", whereas #2, on the contray, could seem too serious if it were used "in one". In #2 using "all" give emphasis and freshness to the sentence, reducing the sense of drama.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got it; *all* is used to refer to three or more things.  We would likely use *both* when only two items are present (though I don't mean to say that "both in one" is a common expression).

So in the first example, she is both a mother and a company director, in one (package).  There are only two items, so you can't add the "all" there.  In your second example there are three items; now we can refer to these three items as "all" and can say "all in one".  Note that the second example would still be correct without the "all", though I'd be more likely to include it.